# Replace token Yaml1 with values from Yaml2

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm, helm3

Yaml1 looks like

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: ((MYAPP_CPU_LIMIT))
    memory: ((MYAPP_MEMORY_LIMIT))
  requests:
    cpu: ((MYAPP_CPU_REQUEST))
    memory: ((MYAPP_MEMORY_REQUEST))
```

and Yaml2

```
variables: 
  MYAPP_CPU_LIMIT: 4
  MYAPP_CPU_REQUEST: 4
  MYAPP_MEMORY_LIMIT: 2Gi
  MYAPP_MEMORY_REQUEST: 2Gi
```

I need to replace the tokens from Yaml1 with values from Yaml2. I know for Azure pipeline scenario, tasks like qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens are available. I am trying to do the same on the developer's machine. I want to know if any command/tool exists to do that.

Comment: You tagged this question with two [Helm](https://helm.sh)-related tags; have you looked into Helm's capabilities, or tried to write this setup as a Helm chart?

Comment: @DavidMaze - Yes, this setup is a part of Helm Charts which use qetza task in the pipeline. I need a workaround for non CI/CD deployments.

Comment: Does Helm syntax like `{{ .Values.variables.MYAPP_CPU_LIMIT }}` work for you?

Comment: In my current setup the yaml1 is actually a values yaml and yaml2 comes from directory structure unrelated to the charts directory. So that syntax would not work for me.